# Using echo|set /P with every available character?

Tags: batch-file

```
set echo|set /P=!variable! >> list.txt
```

Currently this produces a text file that reads like:

```
variablevariablevariablevariable
```

But what I really need is a text file that reads like:

```
"variable": [#name: "differentvariable", #path: "yetanothervariable"], "variable": [#name: "differentvariable", #path: "yetanothervariable"], "variable": [#name: "differentvariable", #path: "yetanothervariable"],
```

and so on and so fourth. Unfortunately if the variables themselves contain ! or &, I get all kinds of issues. I can't figure out how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<nul set /p "=|&<>"
```